# Get list of unique iTunes artists via AppleScript

Tags: applescript, itunes

I'm trying to get lists of unique iTunes artists and genres from my library. AppleScript can be slow with some operations, and in this situation I can't compromise much on speed. Is there any further refactoring I can do to my code?

```
tell application "iTunes"
    -- Get all tracks
    set all_tracks to shared tracks

    -- Get all artists
    set all_artists to {}
    repeat with i from 1 to count items in all_tracks
        set current_track to item i of all_tracks
        set current_artist to genre of current_track
        if current_artist is not equal to "" and current_artist is not in all_artists then
            set end of all_artists to current_artist
        end if
    end repeat
    log all_artists
end tell
```

I feel like there should be an easier way to get a list of artists or genres from iTunes that I'm just not aware of...

Comment: Have you checked out DougScripts? Plenty of scripts there that run blazing fast. There's one specifically for what you're wanting, and can export it to a txt file if you choose. I can't recall the name of it right now but it made quick work of my 74gb of music.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save many Apple Events if you get a list of the property values rather than the track object for example

```
tell application "iTunes"
    -- Get all tracks
    tell shared tracks to set {all_genres, all_artists} to {genre, artist}
end tell
```

Parsing a list of strings consumes no Apple Events at all.

```
-- Get all artists
set uniqueArtists to {}
repeat with i from 1 to count items in all_artists
    set currentArtist to item i of all_artists
    if currentArtist is not equal to "" and currentArtist is not in uniqueArtists then
        set end of uniqueArtists to currentArtist
    end if
end repeat
log uniqueArtists
```

With help of Cocoa (AppleScriptObjC) it's probably much faster. An `NSSet` is a collection type containing unique objects. When a set is created from an array all duplicates are removed implicitly. The method `allObjects()` turns the set back into an array.

```
use framework "Foundation"

tell application "iTunes" to set all_artists to artist of shared tracks
set uniqueArtists to (current application's NSSet's setWithArray:all_artists)'s allObjects() as list
```

Comment: Cool, I hadn't thought about using objective-c to help with this. Didn't know about the short syntax you used in the first part of your answer either. Thank you!